# ¿Cómo implementar function en PHP & HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Creo que es la primera vez que escribo en stackoverflow, desde ya agradezco.

Comento.. Estoy intentando hacer una web por el momento en servidor local con xampp, tengo:

**index.html** (aquí el típico formulario de login en action="#" llama a un archivo login.php).

**login.php** (Debería conectar a la Base de datos, verificar si se conecto y verificar usuarios pasado desde index.html mediante POST.), el problema viene en que dispuse en otro archivo (php) las funciones que necesito para "que este mas ordenado", el problema viene cuando  dentro de function intento establecer conexion con mi base de datos me dice "Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "Conexion" in... (asi lo tengo definido:   $Conexion= Mysqli_Connect($Host, $Usuario, $Contraseña, $DB_name);

si pruebo sin usar las funciones definidas en function no me aparece ningun error.

¿Hay alguna manera de crear una función que permita conectar a una Base de Datos y que sea accesible desde varios formularios si es necesario?.

Busque, modifique, reescribi la función, y sigo como un perro tratando de morderme la cola (es broma) sigo sin encontrar solución.

Espero expresarme bien, y que se entienda lo mejor posible la idea.

Muchas gracias por cualquier dato que pudiera surgir.

Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! En alguna parte de tu código completo estas usando `Conexion` sin la **$**, por lo tanto se cree que es una constante, y de ahí el mensaje de error ese de `Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "Conexion"`. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para realizar mejores preguntas para obtener mejores respuestas.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, estaba bien como tenia todo, excepto que omití por error un signo $, creo que no es lo mismo $Conexion que Conexion. ,D

Comment: Pues borra la pregunta, los errores tipográficos no ayudan a nadie más y son preguntas que a la larga son borradas por moderación (pero si lo haces tu les ahorras trabajo)